# c# XMLReader skips nodes after using ReadElementContentAs

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I am trying to parse an XML file and extract data from elements. The problem is that every time I use ReadElementContentAsX, the reader skips the next element. I don't know why is that. What am I missing?

```
while (reader.Read() && fileValid)
{
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "ID": if (reader.ReadElementContentAsString() != ID)
                {
                    fileValid = false;
                } break;
            case "Size":
                if (reader.ReadElementContentAsInt() != EEPROM_SIZE)
                {
                    fileValid = false;
                }
                break;
            case "Data": if (reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(eeprom_primary, 0, EEPROM_SIZE) != EEPROM_SIZE)
                {
                    fileValid = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML structure is as follows:

`-ParrentNode
--ID:String
--Date:TimeDate
--SoftwareVersionMajor:int
--SoftwareVersionMinor:int
--Size: int
--Data: encodedBase64`

So in my case i read element content for element ID, Size. It will skip element Date and Data. I checked if i remove the readElementContentAs it will not skip the next node

Comment: "What am I missing?" Readable code formatting? (I've outdented the loop, but even so your case statements are horribly hard to read. Hint: when the horizontal scrollbar shows that less than half of your code is visible, it's time to revisit how you're formatting your code...)

Comment: can't help it - when i paste the code here it gets jumbled up a bit ;) and ReadElementContentAsBase64 already does not fit the page with the case statement. However code is work in progress and scrolling a bit should not mess with code perception as the code itself is hardly complicated :)

Comment: You absolutely *can* help it. I managed to edit your code into a more reasonable shape, so what makes you think you can't? I see you've now edited it again and put it *back* into an awful mess. Look at the preview before you post - is that really what you think answerers want to see? And yes, formatting *does* matter even for simple code. If you can't be bothered to make the code readable, why should anyone be bothered to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSND ([ReadElementContentAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

*"This method reads the start tag, the contents of the element, and moves the reader past the end element tag."*

The method is designed to skip to your next element.

EDIT:

You could try it with XmlDocument:

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  loadXML(xmlDoc, "inputfile.xml");
```

And then you can easily process through the Xml file with Xpath expressions and for each loops:

```
  foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/src"))
  {
    // do anything with node
  }
```

Comment: LINQ to XML is *much* nicer API than XmlDocument, IMO. Unless someone is really tied to .NET pre-3.5, I'd go with that...

Comment: Yes, the API is better, without a doubt. I just don't like the way a document is built and how you can access the nodes. The LINQ-Queries look terrible for me; I prefer going through the document with Xpath expressions and foreach loops...

Comment: Whereas I'd much rather use chained methods than encode everything in text that the compiler can't check :) See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/code-and-data/ for more thoughts.

Comment: Nice article, never thought about it like that. I mostly used XSLT and so I had the Xpath expressions already ;)

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of [`ReadElementContentAsString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162529(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method reads the start tag, the contents of the element, and moves the reader past the end element tag.

So you end up at the start of the next element. You then call `Read()` again, which moves *past* the start of that element, either skipping the whole element or moving "into" it so that `IsStartElement()` returns false. So basically, you don't want to call `Read()` at the start of your loop if you've used `ReadElementContentAs*`.

This sort of thing is why I hate `XmlReader`. Unless you *really* need to use it, I'd strongly recommend reading the whole document into memory using LINQ to XML. Even if you *do* need to use `XmlReader`, you can still read one element at a time into LINQ to XML, in a sort of "somewhat streaming" fashion which minimizes your exposure to the reader part.

Comment: hmm... from msdn page it actually says: Moves to the next start element or end element tag.  Thats why i thought it would auto stop at end tag.

Answer (score 0):

hmm. ok figured out myself. just changed the reader.Read() in while condition to !reader.EOF and changed a bit how I read it. works now. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to use XmlReader for whatever reason, XmlReader.ReadString() appears to not have the same issue as XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString().  I just don't know if it will also expand entities and skip processing instructions and comments since I don't have to worry about that for my purpose.